# UNIX: Extracting only the information I need

Tags: unix, awk, grep, ls

I have the following content on a file and I need to extract certain things to another file to make the analysis easier.

---

```
saimptlogi_1~20170208022514~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4403_20170115010230_1.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022549~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4189_20170122010240_1.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022555~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4403_20170116010200_1.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022556~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4189_20170108010210_1.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022610~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4147_20170101010223_1.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022643~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4189_20170107010206_1.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022703~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~STOREDAYNOTREADYTOBELOAD on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4549_20170126010247_7.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022707~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4189_20170114010259_1.dat
saimptlogi_1~20170208022736~procRTLFHead~~103~RET-0103: generic function processing error~DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY on FHEAD record at line 0000000001 in /oretail/apprms/mmhome/data/in/RTLOG_4403_20170108010211_1.dat
```

---

I want to extract the error (**DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY** or **STOREDAYNOTREADYTOBELOAD**) the Store (RTLOG_**4403**_20170108010211_1) and the Date (RTLOG_4403_**20170108**010211_1) to another file and I need the output to be like this:

**Example:**

- DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY 4403 20170108
- STOREDAYNOTREADYTOBELOAD 4549 20170126

I've already developed a command to extract the STORE and the DATE directly from the files (RTLOGS) but it would be better to extract directly from this log file.

**My Command:**
ls {RTLOG*.failed,RTLOG*.rej} | awk -F'|' '{gsub("_"," "); print substr($0,7,13), $4}'

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Oracle?

Comment: Because saimptlogi is a oracle process.

Comment: That is not a reason to tag with Oracle. The Oracle tag is for questions that require an Oracle approach; your question is clearly a UNIX question. (If I have the word "French" in an Oracle table, that is no reason to tag the post with "French", is it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pedro: Try:

```
awk '{match($0,/DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|STOREDAYNOTREADYTOBELOAD/);if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){A=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)};match($0,/RTLOG_.*\.dat/);if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), Q,"_");print A OFS Q[2] OFS substr(Q[3],1,8)}}'  OFS="|"   Input_file
```

Here I am using match functionality of awk and first match I am looking for strings "DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|STOREDAYNOTREADYTOBELOAD" and then checking if substring of RSTART and RLENGTH is present(RSTART and RLENGTH are the variables which will be SET when a match will be found for a regex in a line), if yes then putting variable A's value into substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH).
Then in next match checking for RTLOG_.*dat to get the "RTLOG_4147_20170101010223_1.dat" part from line, if that match is found then using split to split the value of substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) into an array named Q whose delimiter is "_". Then printing the values of variable A Q[2] OFS substr(Q[3],1,8) where Q[2] is 2nd element of array Q which is 4403,4189 and so on, then as per OP's request taking only 8 letters from RTLOG_4403_**20170108010211**_1's highlighted part.

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '{
        match($0,/DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|STOREDAYNOTREADYTOBELOAD/);
        if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){
                                        A=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                                     };
        match($0,/RTLOG_.*\.dat/);
        if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){
                                        split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), Q,"_");
                                        print A OFS Q[2] OFS substr(Q[3],1,8)
                                     }
     }
    '  OFS="|"   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I really love AWK, in this case I'd use sed command to generate an appropiate result:

```
sed -r 's/^.*error.([A-Z]*).*RTLOG_([0-9]*)_([0-9]{8}).*/\1|\2|\3/'
```

That produces something like this:

```
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4403|20170115
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4189|20170122
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4403|20170116
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4189|20170108
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4147|20170101
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4189|20170107
STOREDAYNOTREADYTOBELOAD|4549|20170126
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4189|20170114
DATAUNEXPECTEDSTOREDAY|4403|20170108
```

Comment: I'm trying to run like this:

sed -r err.saimptlogi* 's/^.*error.([A-Z]*).*RTLOG_([0-9]*)_([0-9]{8}).*/\1|\2|\3/'

but I'm receiving the following error:


sed: illegal option -- r
Usage:  sed [-n] script [file...]
        sed [-n] [-e script]...[-f script_file]...[file...]

Comment: Nope, try it like this:

sed -r 'allTheScript' YourFile.txt